# Is there a React-Select prop for delete on backspace when using non-multi Async?

Tags: react-select

I need to be able to clear the selection in the form field when backspace is used. Currently, the any selection is retained in the form field until a new selection is made. I need to be able to clear the selection and show the placeholder again.

This functionality exists in the non-Async version as well as in the Async version, if multi={true} is set. I have tried backspaceRemovesValue={true}, but this prop doesn't seem to be valid for Async.

I expect backspace to remove the form field value in Async as it does for the standard version of React-Select or in the multi- version of Async.

Comment: Would you mind providing the version of the library and a minimal code example of how you use the component?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used `isClearable={true}` but it brings clear indicator